# Joining two lists to create a new list

Tags: python, list

I have two lists and a constant number

```
x =[47, 78, 35, 70, 28, 41]
y = [45, 79, 30, 83, 71, 46]
z=10
```

I want to create a new list which looks like

```
a=[[47,45,10],
   [78,79,10],
   [35,30,10],
   [70,83,10],
   [28,71,10],
   [41,46,10]]
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this

```
res = [[a, b, z] for a, b in zip(x, y)]
print(res)
```

**Output:**

```
[[47, 45, 10],
 [78, 79, 10],
 [35, 30, 10],
 [70, 83, 10],
 [28, 71, 10],
 [41, 46, 10]]
```

Answer (score 0):

`Itertools` has similar functionality with `zip_longest` and it's a quicker than `zip`

```
from itertools import zip_longest

[[a, b, z] for a,b in zip_longest(x,y)]

>>> 
[[47, 45, 10],
 [78, 79, 10],
 [35, 30, 10],
 [70, 83, 10],
 [28, 71, 10],
 [41, 46, 10]]
```